# Gridlines within Tiled Geometry

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to add grid lines to the pattern that I have. What I could come up with so far looks something like the following.

[image]

The XAML code that I have used for this is:

```
 <Border.Background>
   <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,100,100" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
     <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
       <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 H16 V16 H32 V32 H16 V16 H0Z" Brush="Green" />
     </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
   </DrawingBrush>
 </Border.Background>
```

However I would like to add gridlines here to look something like the following:

[image]

Here, there are grid lines within the tiles and the tile edges are slightly thicker.

I am not tiling on some image with the required pattern to avoid hogging on system resource.

Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a brush within a brush, and the outer brush needs to be a 2x2 grid of rectangles or something to get that checkboard pattern. This should do the job:

```
<Border Width="750" Height="750" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Border.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BaseRectangle"  TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#505050" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="151" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="151" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="RectangleA"  TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseRectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Viewport="0,0,30,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile" Viewbox="0,0,30,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Rectangle Stroke="#343434" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#101010" Width="31" Height="31" />
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="RectangleB"  TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseRectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Viewport="0,0,30,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile" Viewbox="0,0,30,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Rectangle Stroke="#343434" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#202020" Width="31" Height="31" />
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Border.Resources>
    <Border.Background>
        <VisualBrush Viewport="0,0.5,300,300" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile" Viewbox="0,0.5,300,300" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas>
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Style="{StaticResource RectangleA}" />
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="150" Style="{StaticResource RectangleB}" />
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="0" Style="{StaticResource RectangleB}" />
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="150" Style="{StaticResource RectangleA}" />
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Result:

[image]

A faster method, if you can get away with it, is to render the checkerboard and grid lines as separate layers. This allows you to render everything with geometries rather than shapes:

```
<Border Width="750" Height="750" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Border.Background>
        <VisualBrush Viewport="0,0.5,300,300" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile" Viewbox="0,0.5,300,300" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas Width="300" Height="300">
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,300,300" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#101010">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,300,300" />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#202020">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <GeometryGroup>
                                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,150,150" />
                                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="150,150,150,150" />
                                            </GeometryGroup>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        </DrawingBrush>
                    </Canvas.Background>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="#505050" StrokeThickness="2" Width="300" Height="300">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <VisualBrush Viewport="0,0.5,30,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile" Viewbox="0,0.5,30,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <Path Stroke="#343434" StrokeThickness="1" Width="31" Height="31" Data="M 0,31 L 0,0 30,0" />
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Comment: It would have taken me a lot of time to figure that out. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Np. I just updated the answer with another option that should have much better performance. Good luck!